# Open function in python3 not writing the text

Tags: python-3.x

I want to make one python file and write text in it but open function makes the file but does not write the text in it. so please help me to solve this. Below is my code:

```
f=open("Bgsrain.py", "a+")
f.write('hello')
```

Comment: Can you tell exactly what is happening? I have tested your program and it works with me.

Comment: yes I want to say that when I made a .py file using open, yes it made the file but didn't write the content I want in it and the new file was blank.

Comment: Unfortunately I am unable to reproduce your problem, as it works as intended when I try this out.

Comment: Mabye try closing the file after using it. ```f.close()```

Comment: @AyushMoghe Don't use close. Use **context managers** instead. Google `with open as`.

Answer (score 0):

The comments are correct, you are missing a `close`:

```py
f=open("Bgsrain.py", "a+")
f.write('hello')
f.close()
```

---

### However:

Do *not* use `close` unless absolutely necessary. Close will not get triggered in case of Exceptions.
If you *need* to use `close`, make sure to wrap it in `try`-`finally`. All in all, it's a hastle to get `close` to work reliably, so try to avoid it.

The recommended alternative is to use **context managers**:

```py
with open("Bgsrain.py", "a+") as f:
   f.write('hello')
```

No `close` required. Leaving the `with` block automatically closes the file.